# Creating dynamic URL with JQuery for Flask

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask

Currently I have a form of filters. I am returning a serialized version of that form with the following code:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if (o[this.name]) {
              if (!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
  };
```

So usually when I am using Flask and I want to create a dynamic URL, I do something like this in the template:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('url_base', selector='{0}'.format(data[]) )}}">{{ data[0] }}, {{ data[1] }}</a>
```

Or something similar. Now, though, I can't just write that in the HTML since I am calculating in with JQuery.

The JSON I have will look something like this:

```
{"first_attr": [1, 54, "pie"], "second_attr": ["tree", "foo"]}
```

And I would like to pass it to flask with a similar structure because it will be going into some python functions that take in `**kwargs`.

How do I, using JQuery, edit the href of an element, let's say a `<button>`, so that it does an AJAX GET request to flask. It can either be by setting the href like `url_for` or it can be done via literal AJAX request. Either way, though, there will need to be something similar to `url_for(base, selector)` to make it happen, I think

Comment: Didn't like my tl;dr reference ? :)

Comment: I thought it was clever, fwiw.

Comment: So I didn't understand that you were looking to create a url on the jquery side. I deleted my answer for now because I haven't had the time to update my incorrect answer. I'll come back around to answer this question when I have a tested and working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up using this [entension](https://github.com/dantezhu/flask_util_js). It allows you to generate URLs client side for flask.

What you have to do:

```
git clone https://github.com/dantezhu/flask_util_js
```

Find the `flask_util_js.py` and stick it in your project

Somewhere in your `.html` template, add `{{ fujs.js }}` to include the code

Then, you can do this somewhere:

```
function onClicked(key) {
    var newURL = flask_util.url_for('your_base', {your_selector: key});
    window.location = newURL;
}
```

Easy as that